# FlexBox menú de navegación, no puedo mover un elemento li

Tags: css, html5, flexbox, menu

Buenas tengo el siguiente código, un simple menú sencillo junto con estos estilos usando FlexBox

```css
    <style>
        *{
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0;
        }
        nav{
            background-color: rgb(19, 19, 19);
        }
        nav ul{
            display: flex;
            list-style: none;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            margin-left: 50px;
            

        }
        nav ul li a{
            color: white;
            font-size: 18px;
            text-decoration: none;

        }
        nav ul li{
            background-color: chocolate;
            display: flex;
            padding: 10px;
            height: 50px;
            align-items: center;
        }
        nav ul li:hover{
            background-color: pink;
        }
        .especial{
          
        }
    </style>
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Novedades</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contacto</a></li>
                <li class="especial"><a  href="">Acerca</a></li> 
                
               
               
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    
</body>
```

Lo que quiero es,usando flexbox y sin usar floats, coger el 4º elemento li -Acerca- que tiene la clase especial (está en blanco en la hoja de estilos lo sé), y mover SÓLO ese elemento li al final del navbar,es decir, los 3 primeros enlaces al principio, y el 4º al final, he probado justify-content: flex end haciéndole un display flex a la clase especial y nada, he probado align-self:flex end a la clase especial y tampoco, y llevo un rato dándole vueltas y no sé lograrlo, imagino que debe ser posible sin necesidad de floats.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para eso sólo tenes que usar la propiedad `margin-left` con el valor `auto`. El porqué esta mejor explicado acá [Uso de márgenes automáticos para la alineación del eje principal](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container#usando_auto_margenes_para_la_alineaci%C3%B3n_en_el_eje_principal) de lo que yo lo podría explicar.

En tu caso el css del elemento `<li class="especial">` quedaría así:

```
.especial {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: Dios Santo, muchas gracias, duda resuelta, le daré el vistazo a lo que me has pasado porque realmente no entiendo por qué hace eso.